# Link opens in the same window (has to be a new window)

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I have a user control (toolbar). It is located in the master page and most pages in the project use this master page and therefore the toolbar user control. Print button in the toolbar control has to open print page in a new window. It is a hyperlink with `target = '_blank'`. In most of the pages it opens in a new window and in only one page it opens in the same window (which is wrong). This weird page has the same master page and hyperlink properties is the same during debugging.

Comment: You should add the relevant code so that people can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange, I would check the markup of that specific page where `target="_blank"` doesn't work and see if it contains any broken markup which could possibly cause that behavior. Maybe the attribute isn't read correctly on that page due to invalid markup somewhere else on that same page.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. I found the issue.